# How to Bind a column of GridView to a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView and i want to bind the first Column(teachername) with a DropDownList which i have outside the GridView. How can i make it work?

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string q = "select * from teacher where teachername='" + drpteachername.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'  and ('2013-03-01' between date and todate) and '2013-03-31' between date and todate";
    dt = dbo.Getdt(q);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    string teachername=drpteachername.SelectedItem.ToString();


    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count ;i++ )
    {
        Label lblteachername = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("lblgridteachername");

                  this.GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = teachername;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the *problem* you having??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Nothing happens which i click button. The above code is neither giving me any results nor any error.

Comment: I am getting error 
{"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using `this.GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = teachername;`

Don't hesitate to write if you feel any confusion.

this statement should be embedded in for loop.

Comment: system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell' does not contain a definition for 'value'

Comment: It is working fine with me. which version of .NET you are using?

Comment: I am using .NET framework 4.0. I have edited my code see if i am doing it right.

Comment: Check by removing last two lines i.e  lblteachername.Text = teachername;
        GridView1.DataBind();  The values should be changed automatically on the execution of this code.

Comment: I guess its happening because  for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count;i++ ) is returning false the first itself since there are no rows in the gridview at present.

Comment: if there is no row in gridview then where you want to replace the values? or you want to add a new row for the selected teachername?

Comment: i have edit my code once again. The datatable has one row. But i am getting error :  {"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"}

Comment: remove = sign. Just use < sign. because index starts from 0 and will end at rows.count-1. let me edit your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in prerender event.

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblteachername = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblgridteachername");
         lblteachername.Text = teachername; 
    }
```